# How delete row from UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would to delete a row in my tableview. I'm using SQLite.
How to implement deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are not deleting the row....

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Needs to be added in the commitEditingStyle delegate function...

[See Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)